# How do you tell the difference between review of a path and the next path?

Tags: stages-of-the-path

In the same way the buddha referred to those who wander through Jhana as foolish cows, can individuals wander and get lost within the cycles of insight?

> When the meditator has thus become skilled in achieving the fruition attainment, he should resolutely set his mind upon the task of attaining to the higher paths and fruitions. What should now be done by one who has set himself that task? Just as before, he should carry out the practice of noticing (anything occurring) at the six sense doors.

Can next path start without being skilled in fruition attainment?

For example, if I am able to advert to A&P but not able to advert to fruition, is that proof I am still reviewing the last path, or can it be that I moved on too soon?

Sorry if this is convoluted, I am looking for an actual answer as opposed to a non answer.

Comment: Do you mean the view on what the path is and the actual path?

Answer (score 3):

Some useful [teachings by Ajaan Fuang](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/thai/fuang/itself.html) on this topic below.

Ajaan Fuang teaches not to plan how the meditation would go, or deliberately look out for signs to determine what stage you're at, or to be obsessed about what the next steps should be. Instead, he teaches to go on practising by oneself to find out how things will turn out.

From my understanding, one should not just reach one stage and then rush over to the next. One should instead master one stage, then go on to master the next.

In my opinion, it is also useful to have such a teacher to guide the student when he finds that the student has reached an impasse or is going on the wrong path. Otherwise, if the teacher finds that the student is progressing on the right path, he should allow the student to discover the next steps on his own.

Quote:

> § When Ajaan Fuang taught meditation, he didn't like to map things out
>   in advance. As soon as he had explained the beginning steps, he'd have
>   the student start sitting right in his presence, and then take the
>   steps back home to work on there. If anything came up in the course of
>   the practice, he'd explain how to deal with it and then go on to the
>   next step.
>
> Once a layman who had known more than his share of meditation teachers
>   came to discuss the Dhamma with Ajaan Fuang, asking him many questions
>   of an advanced nature as a way of testing his level of attainment.
>   Ajaan Fuang asked him in return, "Have you had these experiences in
>   your own meditation yet?"
>
> "No, not yet."
>
> "Then in that case I'd rather not discuss them, **because if we discuss
>   them when they're not yet a reality for you, they'll just be theories,
>   and not the real Dhamma.**"
>
> § One meditator noticed that his practice under Ajaan Fuang was making
>   quick progress, and so he asked what the next step would be. "I'm not
>   going to tell you," Ajaan Fuang said. "Otherwise you'll become the
>   sort of amazing marvel who knows everything before he meets with it,
>   and masters everything before he's tried his hand. **Just keep
>   practicing and you'll find out on your own.**"
>
> § "**You can't plan the way your practice is going to go.** The mind has
>   its own steps and stages, and you have to let the practice follow in
>   line with them. That's the only way you'll get genuine results.
>   Otherwise you'll turn into a half-baked arahant."
>
> § "Don't make a journal of your meditation experiences. If you do,
>   you'll start meditating in order to have this or that thing happen, so
>   that you can write it down in your journal. And as a result, you'll
>   end up with nothing but the things you've fabricated."

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. One way of reading it is that it seems to be saying, "Ajaan Fuang says you shouldn't be asking questions". Can you explain more clearly how it relates to the OP's question?

Comment: @ChrisW Updated for clarity.